# Multiple OR conditions not working IF statement

Tags: apex, trigger

In my `Apex Trigger` I have code that I want to execute when any of the conditions are met.

```
trigger NewLeadSendToInfusionsoft on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
       if(l.LeadSource != 'dup' || l.LeadSource != 'Package Installation' || l.Email != null || l.Status != 'At Infusionsoft') {

           LeadInfusionsoft.sendNewLeadToInfusionsoft(l.FirstName, l.LastName, l.Title, l.Company,
                                                      l.Street, l.City, l.State, l.PostalCode,
                                                      l.Country, l.Phone, l.MobilePhone, l.Email, l.LeadSource);
       }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is it always executes, even though in the debug log it says the `Email` field is `null`.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have `a != b || a != c` where `b != c`, it will always be true. In this case, you always know this part of the clause will return true:

```
l.LeadSource != 'dup' || l.LeadSource != 'Package Installation'
```

It seems like you may just want to join all your clauses with `&&` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Because you are using OR conditions. || is OR. So you basically have

```
if( l.LeadSource NOT EQUAL TO 'Package Installation' OR l.Email NOT EQUAL TO null )
```

Even if l.Email is null l.LeadSource may not be Package Installation (Which is also a condition to execute).